# Apache Airflow: operator to copy s3 to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

What is the best operator to copy a file from one s3 to another s3 in airflow?
I tried S3FileTransformOperator already but it required either transform_script or select_expression. My requirement is to copy the exact file from source to destination.

Comment: Airflow 1.10.3 now has an [S3CopyObjectOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135735/apache-airflow-operator-to-copy-s3-to-s3).

Comment: Link points back to this page btw, you probably want this: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/s3_copy_object_operator.html

Answer (score 6):

Use `S3CopyObjectOperator`

```
copy_step = S3CopyObjectOperator(
   source_bucket_key='source_file',
   dest_bucket_key='dest_file',
   aws_conn_id='aws_connection_id',
   source_bucket_name='source-bucket',
   dest_bucket_name='dest-bucket'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options (even when I disregard `Airflow`)

1. Use **AWS CLI**: [`cp` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

   - `aws s3 cp <source> <destination>`
   - In `Airflow` this command can be run using `BashOperator` (local machine) or `SSHOperator` (remote machine)
2. Use **AWS SDK** aka `boto3`

   - Here you'll be using `boto3`'s [`S3Client`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)
   - Airflow already provides a wrapper over it in form of `S3Hook`
   - Even [`copy_object(..)` method of `S3Client`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) is available in [`S3Hook` as (again) `copy_object(..)`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py#L459)
   - You can use `S3Hook` inside any suitable custom `operator` or just `PythonOperator`