# How can I export HDFS file in S3 to local machine as CSV file using Airflow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hdfs, airflow

I want to create an airflow job to export hdfs file stored in S3 to local machine. Which airflow operator could be used for this

Answer (score 2):

There is no particular Airflow operator that can fully satisfy your needs, however as for mine I see two options(ways) how to potentially address this:

1. A basic approach, using *AWS CLI* util, invoking *[cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)* command in Airflow [BashOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/bash.html#bashoperator) that is leveraging Bash instruments to copy target S3 file to the local destination, this method was already discussed in this Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136104/9928809) but in a bit different scenario.
2. Besides Operators, Airflow contains a flexible mechanism called [Hooks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#hooks) that widely extends Operators functionality by implementing communication channel to the external platforms. There is [S3_hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/hooks/S3_hook/index.html#module-airflow.hooks.S3_hook) module that aims to afford AWS S3 related operations, originally based on AWS `boto3` library. However, probably you will not find the suitable method through the list of contains, that you might be interesting in. But recently I've discovered [S3_to_hive_operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/s3_to_hive_operator/index.html#module-airflow.operators.s3_to_hive_operator), after inspecting the entire structure and [source](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/s3_to_hive_operator.html#S3ToHiveTransfer) code, I've found `execute()` Python function that triggers `boto3` [download_fileobj()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html) method, downloading file from S3 bucket to local drive. Therefore, you can adopt custom Airflow [Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/custom-operator.html), supplying it with partially modified `execute()` function in the particular `S3_hook` method.

Hope it can be helpful for you research.